# SVG filter that fills area between two polylines

Tags: svg, filter

i am trying to learn how SVG filters work and came up with the following situation:

There is an input SVG like this, minimal example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline id="outer" points="50.0,10.0 90.0,90.0 10.0,90.0 50.0,10.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
  <polyline id="inner" points="35.0,50.0 65.0,50.0 50.0,80.0 35.0,50.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Now my quest is to create a filter that does not need to change the two polylines but adds color to the SVG *between* the two polylines.

My naive idea is:

1.) replicate the `outer` object and fill its inside space with some color.

2.) replicate the `inner` object the same way and fill it with the same color

3.) add the difference of both to the image (with a Z-position below the original polylines so they stay visible)

My first attempt looks like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="fillingFilter">
      <use href="#inner" style="fill:green" />
      <feComposite in2="sourceGraphic" operator="out" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polyline id="outer" points="50.0,10.0 90.0,90.0 10.0,90.0 50.0,10.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
  <polyline id="inner" points="35.0,50.0 65.0,50.0 50.0,80.0 35.0,50.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
  <use href="#outer" filter="url(#fillingFilter)" style="fill:green" />
</svg>
```

This does not work, as the added fillings are ignored, and this way the composite seems to do nothing.
From studying the SVG documentation i can't really find out how to do it.

What is the right way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a filter for this - just convert your polylines to a **compound path**.

- Concatenate both polyline `points` attributes:
- Prepend a `M` (Moveto - starting point) command and append a `z` command (closepath)
- copy these values to a `<path>` `<d>` attribute like so:

  `<path d="M 50.0,10.0 90.0,90.0 10.0,90.0 50.0,10.0 z M 35.0,50.0 65.0,50.0 50.0,80.0 35.0,50.0 z" fill-rule="evenodd" />`
- add a `fill-rule="evenodd"` – this way inner shapes will be subtracted from the outer shape.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline id="outer" points="50.0,10.0 90.0,90.0 10.0,90.0 50.0,10.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
  <polyline id="inner" points="35.0,50.0 65.0,50.0 50.0,80.0 35.0,50.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="outer" 
        d="
          M 50.0,10.0 90.0,90.0 10.0,90.0 50.0,10.0z
          M 35.0,50.0 65.0,50.0 50.0,80.0 35.0,50.0z" 
        fill-rule="evenodd" 
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="1" 
        fill="green" />
</svg>
```

#### Combine polylines via javaScript helper

You can easily automate this process by writing a simple helper method.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
polysToPath(svg)

function polysToPath(svg){
  let polylines = document.querySelectorAll('polyline');
  // create compound path
  let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
  svg.insertBefore(path, polylines[0]);
  
  // combinded path data
  let d = '';
  polylines.forEach(poly=>{
    d += 'M'+poly.getAttribute('points')+'z';
    //remove polyline
    poly.remove();
  }) 
  
  path.setAttribute('d', d);
  // style new path via css class or attributes
  path.classList.add('polyPath');
  //path.setAttribute('fill-rule', 'evenodd');
  //path.setAttribute('fill', 'green');
}
```

```css
svg{
  width:20em
}

.polyPath{
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  fill:green;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline id="outer" points="50.0,10.0 90.0,90.0 10.0,90.0 50.0,10.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
  <polyline id="inner" points="35.0,50.0 65.0,50.0 50.0,80.0 35.0,50.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, this looks so elegant and simple to understand. Thank you!

Apart from its complexity, there is one aspect that i did not address in my question: Imagine the paths consist of many many coordinates. In that case one might want to avoid their duplication. Is it somehow possible to create the new evenodd-ly composed path from two separate preexisting ones?

Comment: You can automate this process by a little javaScript helper - see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Points are for herrstrietzel.

You can shorten his code with a native Web Component, supported in all modern browsers:

```html
<svg-merge-polylines>
  <polyline points="50.0,10.0 90.0,90.0 10.0,90.0 50.0,10.0"/>
  <polyline points="35.0,50.0 65.0,50.0 50.0,80.0 35.0,50.0"/>
</svg-merge-polylines>

<script>
customElements.define("svg-merge-polylines", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML/lightDOM is parsed
      let d = [...document.querySelectorAll('polyline')]
                .map(p => 'M' + p.getAttribute('points') + 'z');
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="height:180px">` +
        `<path d="${d.join("")}" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="green"/>` +
        `</svg>`;
    });
  }
})
</script>
```